# How can I delay the start of a CSS animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to delay the trigger of a CSS animation (not slow down the animation itself, but delay it a few seconds before starting). And the image should not display before the animation runs. I looked through the other questions, and they don't seem to address this.

MY FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/omarel/guh5f8bs/

CSS

```
.slideRight{

    animation-name: slideRight;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideRight;   

    animation-duration: 1s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;   
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;       

    visibility: visible !important;   
}

@keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-150%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }   
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-150%);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="slideRight">
    HI
</div>
```

Side note: Also is there a way to get it to work with an `<a>` tag? Animations don't seem to play nice with this:

```
<a class="slideRight">
    HI
</a>
```

Comment: Use [animation-delay](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp)

Comment: webkit-animation-delay -> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp

Comment: Omar, I've updated my answer just now and it addresses both of your questions. Let me know if it solves your problem or if there's still some issue to work out.

Answer (score 19):

Delaying the start of the animation is *very* simple. Simply add the [animation-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) property to your code:

```css
.slideRight{
    animation-name: slideRight;
    animation-duration: 1s;   
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;        
    visibility: visible !important;
    /* New code here: */
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

It's important to note that `animation-delay` only delays the *start* of the animation from the beginning. If you have a repeating animation, it won't add the delay to the same spot of each loop; only to the very beginning. There's currently no CSS property capable of that kind of looped delay.

All major browsers currently support `animation-delay` without the need for vendor prefixes.

---

As for your second question regarding the `<a>` element: Yes, it can work. The reason it's not working for you now is because `<a>` elements are [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) elements. In order to make it work like you're expecting, add `display: inline-block;` to the `.slideRight{}` selector. Ultimately this is what your code will look like:

```css
.slideRight{
    animation-name: slideRight;
    animation-duration: 1s;   
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;     
    visibility: visible !important;
    /* New code here: */
    animation-delay: 1s;
    display: inline-block;
}


@keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-150%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }   
}
```

```html
<a class="slideRight">HI</a>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/gvckqL4n/)

Comment: @Steve The animation moves it left and then slides it back in right. So if you delay the animation, you'll see it in the default position for 1s, and then the animation will play. Try setting the delay to 3s for a more obvious display.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right. After seeing it in action though it looked funny. Well, if that's what they're looking for! Good answer, I tip my hat good sir.

Comment: @Steve You're right though, it does *look* wonky. OP would be better served, I think, to display the element off the page to begin with, and then play the `SlideRight` keyframe.

Comment: @TylerH Agreed. Looks much smoother if that's the end game solution. Wonky is the perfect description.

Answer (score 1):

## Add a settimeout function

Hi there, you could add an event listen that get when you mouseover the certain element and then calls the function after 1 second.

```
$('slideRight').on('mouseover',function(){

window.setTimeout(function(){
    $this.addClass('onesecond');
}, 1000); //<-- Delay in milliseconds
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

Source:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay